# JInternalFrame how hide all system button popup menu (max, min, resore..)

Tags: java, swing

Help how hide all system menu from JInternalFrame. (not super("title", false, false, false, false);) but completely remove button (in Numbs LookandFeel).

Comment: please edit your post with http://sscce.org/

Comment: *"Numbs LookandFeel"*  What is "Numbs" PLAF?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
JInternalFrame.putClientProperty("JInternalFrame.isPalette", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Make sure that close button is invisible:

```
JInternalFrame.setClosable(false);
```